# Can I affect instance variables/properties from within a block?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have defined an array variable using `@property (strong, nonatomic) __block NSArray *users;`, and I try to change it inside a block using `self.users = ...;`. The block is sent as a parameter to `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler]`. The `sendAsynchronousRequest` method is called from a method which is called in the `viewDidLoad` method of my "Table View Controller".

When I call `[awesomeObject.users count]` I get **0**.

As a slight tangent, do I need to implement the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods `didReceiveResponse`, `didReceiveData` and `connectionDidFinishLoading` when using `sendAsynchronousRequest`?

**Edit:** 
Right. I just realized that `numberOfRowsInSection` is being called *before* the block executes. I had forgotten to add a notification to tell the table view to reload itself. Sending out a notification from inside the block has fixed the problem.

Comment: You dont need to implement the delegate method, since you are using the completion handler. But, are you sure you have the objects inside array.

Comment: @insane-36 I realized the problem literally moments after posting - See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was forgetting to reload my table view after processing the data. I sent out a notification from inside the block which is heard by the Table View Controller, causing the table to be reloaded once the data has been processed.